# Drag & Drop - GetData() returning null

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to drag&drop some items of a treeview (WPF) to a DataGrid (WinForms).

Unfortunately, I can't receive the data in the drop event:

```
System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e;

foreach (string format in e.Data.GetFormats(true))
{
    object data = e.Data.GetData(format); //Returns null
}
```

My `data` is always null.

I'm trying to get the Data of the format "ADClientAble":

[image]

How can I access the property `innerData`?

I've tried it via reflection, but it's not working:

```
var oleConverterType = Type.GetType("System.Windows.DataObject+OleConverter, PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35");
var oleConverter = typeof(System.Windows.Forms.DataObject).GetField("innerData", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(e.Data);

var dataObject = (System.Windows.Forms.DataObject)oleConverterType.GetProperty("OleDataObject").GetValue(oleConverter, null); //Throws an error: 


var item = dataObject.GetData(this.Format);
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Object does not match target type.

Comment: System.Windows.DataObject vs. System.Windows.Forms.DataObject?

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes.. So System.Windows.Forms.DataObject to System.Windows.DataObject..

Comment: What I meant: Your `oleConverter` object is of type `System.Windows.Forms.DataObject.OleConverter`. You cannot pass it to the GetValue method of a FieldInfo you get from the `System.Windows.DataObject.OleConverter` type.

Comment: @KlausGütter Is there any other solution/way to access the innerData?

Comment: What about `var dataObject = (System.Windows.Forms.DataObject)oleConverter.GetType().GetProperty("OleDataObject").GetValue(oleConverter, null);`

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: "Unable to cast object of type "System.Windows.DataObject" to type "System.Windows.Forms.DataObject."

Comment: So `var dataObject = (System.Windows.DataObject)oleConverter.GetType().GetProperty("OleDataObject").GetValue(oleConverter, null);`. Good luck.